# Не подключатся к бд mysql

Tags: python, mysql, telebot

[image: Код]
[image: Код]

Python,либа телебот.делаю что бы при команде /start в боте в бд добавлялся id созданный мной,без команды работает то есть обьект создается и подключение вроде есть,а когда с ней что то с подключением

Comment: Постарайтесь следовать правилам оформления вопросов на SO. Код и текст ошибки следует приводить в виде текста, а не картинкой - это будет более читабельно и посик по тексту будет работать. Кроме того использовать ответы для дополнений вопроса не следует - просто отредактируйте свой вопрос, кликнув на кнопку "править" (под вопросом)

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `cursor.execute()` ожидает в качестве второго параметра кортеж или список параметров, а вы ему передаете скаляр.

Попробуйте так:

```
 parms = (message.chat.id, )
 # NOTE:  -------------> ^      # this makes it tuple
 cursor.execute(sql, parms)
```

---

наглядный пример:

```
In [1]: parms = (123)

In [2]: type(parms)
Out[2]: int
```

тип переменной `parms` - `int` вместо ожидаемого `tuple`. Правильно делать так:

```
In [3]: parms = (123, )

In [4]: type(parms)
Out[4]: tuple
```

Comment: спасибо большое!)